# How to add multiple contacts at a single call through Getresponse api

Tags: php, getresponse

I am trying to add subscriber to list through Getresponse api for single contact subscription to list i have to call api like this

```
$getresponse = new GetResponse(api key);
                    $result = $getresponse->addContact(listid,
                        $lead['name'],
                        $lead['email']
                    );
```

Now i want to add multiple emails at a single call, i cant use foreach loop for each contact, is there a function or endpoint to add multiple emails at a single call?

Answer (score 3):

Getresponse official API shows only one contact.

https://apidocs.getresponse.com/v3/resources/contacts#contacts.create

As of now, there is no API endpoints for import contacts as bulk (csv or JSON).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Bala is correct. There is no such API method for GetResponse to insert multiple contacts. However, please check the below API codes to insert single contact to GetResponse.

`include('GetResponseAPI3.class.php');`

`$getresponse = new GetResponse('your-getresponse-token-here');`

`$var = $getresponse->addContact(array`
    `(`
    `'name' => 'FirstName LastName',`
    `'email' => 'emailid@something.com',`
    `'dayOfCycle' => 0,`
    `'campaign' => array('campaignId' => 'Campaign-id'),`
    `'ipAddress' => 'XXX.XXX.XX.XX'`
    `)`
`);`

`var_dump($var);`